# Route protecting of a Login page in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to protect routes in my React app. The `Home` page is being protected, but I also want to stop the user to go back to the login page if the `isLoggedIn` is true, and if it is false then he can't access the home and will be redirected to the `Login` page.
This is the `PrivateRoutes` that I have written to protect the routes which is protecting the home but the user can still access the `Login` page, how can I stop this?

PrivateRoutes.jsx:

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = true;
  return isLoggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

This is the App.jsx:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import SignUp from "./pages/SignUp";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import PrivateRoutes from "./utils/PrivateRoutes";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} path="/" exact />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to prevent authenticated access to the `"/login"` route then you can also protect that route under a similar condition as the private routes. Create another layout route component that applies the ***inverse*** condition of the `PrivateRoute` component, e.g. it redirects users that ***are*** authenticated.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = true;
  return isLoggedIn 
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const AnonymousRoute = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = true;
  return isLoggedIn 
    ? <Navigate to="/" replace />
    : <Outlet />;
};

export default AnonymousRoute;
```

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import SignUp from "./pages/SignUp";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import PrivateRoute from "./utils/PrivateRoute";
import AnonymousRoute from "./utils/AnonymousRoute";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Route>
        <Route element={<AnonymousRoute />}>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

import { Outlet, Navigate, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = true; // Replace with your authentication logic
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      navigate("/home");
    } else {
      navigate("/login");
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn, navigate]);

  return <Outlet />;
};

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

> isLoggedIn value with your actual authentication logic. This way, you
> ensure that the login and home pages are appropriately protected based
> on the user's authentication status